# Move files with exception in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

It works fine when I wrote this code on bash shell

```sh
mv -v `pwd`/!(.git) `pwd`/NewDir
```

But if I create shell script file like below,(name of this file is "s.sh")

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mv -v `pwd`/!(.git) `pwd`/NewDir
```

it returns error

```sh
./s.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./s.sh: line 2: `mv -v `pwd`/(!.git) `pwd`/NewDir'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: oops it was miss spelling! sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

`!(.git)` is an extended glob, you need to enable `extglob` to make it work in a non-interactive shell. And I think instead of calling `pwd` twice, you can use `PWD` variable in this case.

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -v "$PWD"/!(.git) "$PWD/NewDir"
```

Comment: thank you!! It works now! learned a lot :)